# How can you write to an Object File from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, hex, fs, object-files

I have a string with hexadecimal code for an object file I have generated in a program previously in my JavaScript file. How can I create an object file with this code, preferably with the `fs` module?

So far, I've tried using the `hex` and `binary` encoding options:

`fs.writeFileSync("output.out", program, { encoding: 'hex' })`

Comment: can you give more information and an attempt you have made at this so we can help debug? see [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Will edit the question now, thanks

Comment: What is "string with hexadecimal code for an object file"?  I don't know what that is and I don't know what you want the contents of the file to be.  If you're just trying to write the string to the file, you can just write it.  If you're trying to do some decoding or encoding first, you have to show us what you start with and what you want to end up with inside the file.  Right now, this question is unclear and does not contain any sort of minimal, reproducible example.

Comment: You don't write a string if you want to write binary. You write binary when you want to write binary. Write the original value probably in a `Buffer` to the file. No encoding needed (that's only needed for text). See [the documentation for `writeFileSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fswritefilesyncfile-data-options) which leads to [the docs for `writeFile`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fswritefilefile-data-options-callback)